# Database - Table Design for User Type Individual User and Organization User

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

Im new here so please bear with me here.

Okay, so I have this problem where the user, either an individual user type (admin) or an organization user type (group of people), logs in to my website.

User information may vary depending on the user type (an admin can have an age, birthday, first name, last name and other individual-related info while an organization has organization name, date created, list of officers, organization status, and other organization-related info)

I also need to make a user-to-user messaging system. Example is a message of organization-to-individual or vice versa and individual-to-individual

Anyone knows how i should do this? Any help is appreciated

In the meantime

This is how I think it goes for messaging (currently having troubles thinking a solution for my problem):

```
TABLE Users
UserAccountNumber varchar(20) Example : 2016-02081-ORG
UserPassword varchar(20)
UserTypeID tinyint Example : 0 for admin, 1 for organizations



TABLE Message
MessageID varchar(20) Example: GF23DG2VS45G <- RANDOM GENERATED
SenderID varchar(20) <- UserAccountNumber FK
ReceiverID varchar(20) <- UserAccountNumber FK
Time_Message datetime

TABLE MESSAGE_TEXT
MessageTextID varchar(20)
MessageID <- FK
Body varchar(255) <- message Example : "Hello, how are you?"
Time_Message datetime
```

Feel free to redesign my messaging table design to help me improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use VARCHAR as your ID. Use an INT (or bigint/long) and have it generated either through an auto incrementing mechanism on the table (mysql) or a sequence (oracle/postgres)

In your case, an admin and an organization `is-a` user, so you may want to consider `database inheritance`. The user table is the base with shared attributes. If you don't have shared attributes than all it needs is an user_id column and a `type discriminator` column, which can have a value of either "admin" or "organization". Your admin and organization table will have their primary key be user_id, and it will also be a foreign key back to user. You would want to have `BEFORE INSERT triggers` on admin and organization that would first insert into user, and inject the generated user_id into the respective table.

Are the admins going to be list of officers for the organization? This assumes so:

```
user
----
user_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
user_type VARCHAR CHECK (user_type in ('admin', 'organization')) -- This is called the discriminator
-- other shared attributes go here, if any

admin -- this extends user
----
user_id INT PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES USER (id)
first_name VARCHAR
last_name VARCHAR
age INT
birth_date DATE
organization_id INT REFERENCES organization (user_id) -- an admin belongs to an organization

organization -- this extends organization
------------
user_id INT PRIMARY KEY REFERENCS USER (id)
name VARCHAR
incorporation_date DATE
```

Now, for the messaging system. I would just combine your `message` and `message` text into one.

```
message
-------
message_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
parent_message_id INT UNIQUE REFERENCES message (message_id) # This lets you keep track of replies
sender_id INT REFERENCES user (user_id)
receiver_id INT REFERENCS user (user_id)
dt DATETIME
message_body TEXT
```

Of course, if you wanted to be able to send to multiple people instead of only one:

```
message
-------
message_id INT PRIMARY KEY
parent_message_id INT UNIQUE REFERENCES message (message_id) # This lets you keep track of replies 
sender_id INT REFERENCES user (user_id)
dt DATETIME
message_body TEXT

message_receiver
---------------
message_id PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES message (message_id)
receiver_id INT PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES user (user_id)
type VARCHAR CHECK (type in ('TO', 'CC", 'BCC')) -- This would let you do an normal email To, Carbon Copy, Blind Carbon Copy if you wished
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer man..Why is it bad to have an varchar ID? is it not a good practice? also, in the message_receiver table you made, is the message_receiver.meesage_id  also a FK to  Table Message? I appreciate your anwer man :_ thanks a lot!

Comment: @NitchexKris If you use a randomly generated varchar as your ID, you have a chance (albeit very small) of generating a duplicate key on an insert, which would fail because of the primary key constraint. By using an int as your ID, and having those int's generated by `auto_increment` or by a `sequence`, you will never have any chance of duplicates.

Comment: @NitchexKris Yep, message_receiver.message_id is a FK to message.message_id. Good luck on your database endeavors!

Comment: thank you kind sir ! :)) regarding the random generated id, i have i function that generates a key which also check if the generated key is in the database already. if it does it will generate again until it becomes valid...but oh well..thank you again

Comment: A question my good sir :) **message.parent_mesage_id** is a unique key referenced to  **message.message_id** ? so, does mean they have the same value right? could you explain how it would track the replies? Thank you my good sir! :)

Comment: @NitchexKris In the message.parent_message_id has two possible values: null, or the message_id of a different row. The first message a user sends will have a message_id of 1, and a parent_message_id of null. If another user replies to this message, the new message will have a message_id of 2, and a parent_message_id of 1. We can see that the second message is a reply to the first message because parent_message_id points to the message_id of the first parent.  Search for "self-referential" on this page: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561

Comment: Woahhh..I see..you're good man.. Thanks :) is there anyway i could get you a reward or anything? like, give you stars or points?..coz i'll give you man..you deserve it...Okay it all make sense now :) thank you my good sir! :)

Comment: Yes, you can hit the Up arrow next to the left of the start of my answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. Make a table for organizations and people. Link them back to 'users' with the account number or even better an integer id field. Each message should also have an id field which links messages to users. Then for any message you can find the user and user's info from the appropriate table.

Comment: Yes, I made a Table-per-Type for the people and organization that links back them to Table **'User'** where the attributes in table users are anything they have in common.
What do you man by id field? isn't that MessageID (id field?) ? How would you do it? I don't quite understand. Sorry. But thanks for your answer I appreciate it. :)

Comment: The id for each table should just be an auto-incremented integer. There's no need for varchar columns, but yes, your messageId field does the job.